# Material not applied properly

Tags: materials

I was just testing some materials and i made a simple jeans model so i can put the denim material on it, i was using the lily scapper add on, when denim material was put on only a small part of the model had the material and the rest only had like a stretched version of the texture like blue or something.
When i went to uv editing to edit the position of the faces, i select faces but on the uv editor they show up as an edge. If anyone can help i would appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if this will work, but here's something you can try:
first remove the texture, go into object mode, select the jeans, and apply the scale using ctrl+a. 
Then go into edit mode with your jeans, use "a" to select everything, and hit u -> UV unwrap. I think this will generate a different set of faces.
Finally add the texture back on using lily's surface scraper.

Comment: Thanks man, appreciate it